# Rake searchkick reindex on heroku not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to get searchkick to reindex on the heroku application. It currently reindexs fine on the localhost.

The command i run on localhost is this

```
rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Newevent
```

I've been following the github tutorial and got to this

```
heroku run rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Newevent
```

Which currently returns this,

```
 heroku run rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Newevent
Running rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Newevent on //APPNAMEREMOVED//... up, run.7334
rake aborted!
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://heroku congif:0
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/utils.rb:258:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/utils.rb:258:in `URI'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:309:in `url_prefix='
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:77:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:47:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:47:in `block in __build_connections'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:36:in `map'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:36:in `__build_connections'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:34:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:105:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:105:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport.rb:26:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.14/lib/elasticsearch/transport.rb:26:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick.rb:43:in `client'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/index.rb:510:in `client'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/index.rb:148:in `clean_indices'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/index.rb:161:in `reindex_scope'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/model.rb:51:in `searchkick_reindex'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => searchkick:reindex
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm happy to share more code if needed, Just not sure what you'd need so i havent included loads

Thanks

Comment: Judging by this snippet I'd guess that some part of your configuration has a syntax error or typo in it: “http://heroku congif:0”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the elastic search url in your `config/secrets.yml`

```
production:
  secret_key_base:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  elastic_search_url: http://localhost:9200
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation for searchkick: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick

There is a section for configuring the application HEROKU.  The gem references `ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_URL"]` for the search URL.  I don't recommend putting the URL in your configuration files.  The Heroku way is to use ENV variables.